# Element lose proportions on different screens

Tags: html, css

As the topic says my [website](http://www.smbjob.co.il) is having troubles with the navigation.

Here the picture is taken from 19' monitor (look at the gap that I marked in a red color)
[image]

Here is the same site but from 23' monitor (there is no gap)
[image]

I thought that this would work, but it didn't:

Pseudo:

```
#header{position: relative; width: 100%; height: 8%;}
#nav{position: absolute; bottom: 0; right: 10%; height: 3%;}
```

**I thought that this approach will work, and the header will look the same at all standard computer screens**

---

**I have edited my CSS according to Tanner answer**

[image]

in 22' monitor(looks fine):
[image]

in 23' monitor(there is a difference):
[image]

**How can i make the navigation at bottom 0 in each screen?**

Comment: I will appreciate if someone will explain to me why to rate "-1", I described it as detailed as i could.

Answer (score 0):

So your height is percent based, meaning it will shrink with the browser window as 8% of a 19' monitor is less than 8% of a 23' monitor.

If you set a `min-height:75px;` on your `#header` element instead of using a percentage, it will stop it shrinking beyond that point and change it to `position: fix;`

```
#header{position: fix; width: 100%; height: 8%; min-height:75px;}
```

Comment: i thought that it will work.. can you please take a look at http://smbjob.co.il/  ? i updated it and putted min-height on the id="header", but no change.

Comment: @slash1z have edited, just take off your percentage based height altogether and leave height:75px

Comment: actually you previous answer helped a lot + the height to navigation and the position, if you will update your answer i will accept it.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix it:

what i did was:(the header suppose to be with position: fix;)

```
#header{position: fix; width: 100%; height: 6.9%; min-height: 68px;}
#navigation{position: absolute; bottom: 0; right: 21%; height: 37px;}
```

this set the navigation at the bottom 0 on each screen.